# Angelscript - RegisterScriptArray fails

Tags: c++, angelscript

i am trying to get an angelscript test running, however, calling `RegisterScriptArray()` fails

```
System function (1, 39) : ERR  : Expected '<end of file>'
 (0, 0) : ERR  : Failed in call to function 'RegisterObjectBehaviour' with 'array' and 'array<T>@ f(int&in type, int&in list) {repeat T}' (Code: -10)
```

the code is:

```
engine = asCreateScriptEngine(ANGELSCRIPT_VERSION);

// message callback
int r = engine->SetMessageCallback(asFUNCTION(as_messageCallback), 0, asCALL_CDECL); assert( r >= 0 );

RegisterStdString(engine);
RegisterScriptArray(engine, false);

r = engine->RegisterGlobalFunction("void print(const string &in)", asFUNCTION(as_print), asCALL_CDECL); assert( r >= 0 );
```

What should i do? If i comment out the call it works, but thats obviously not what i want to archieve as i want arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking on their forums I got a reply (actually quite some time ago).

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/657233-registerscriptarray-fails

In case the link dies:

The main issue was a version mismatch between the plugins (which I compiled and installed manually) and the core (which I installed through my package manager). Now I include the plugins in my code and the core is manually compiled.

Hope it helps others encountering the same issue.

Comment: You may want to include the essential parts of the solution here (if you're allowed to), in case the link you gave goes out of date in the future.